# Números altos en el margin

Tags: html, css

quería saber si es corrector poner números altos para el margin, por ejemplo tengo este código, lo que quiero es poner un texto en el centro de la pantalla, pero no se me ocurre de otra manera, pero no sé si es la forma mas correcta, disculpa si la pregunte es muy sencilla. Pero no encuentro la información que busco

```css
div{
margin-top: 25%;
text-align:center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend+Tera&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
 
<body>
 <div>

  <H1>Esto es una prueba</H1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poner el div que contiene al texto al centro de la pantalla, apoyate de flexbox así

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        body{
          margin: 0px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          background-color: pink;
          height: 100vh;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>Hola Mundo SO</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- Con la primer opción centras horizontalmente
- Con la segunda opción centras verticalmente

> body es la etiqueta padre que contiene a div, entonces con las propiedades indicadas le decimos que sus hijos, en este caso el div sean cajas flexibles.